# Swift dynamicType does not work with generic function

Tags: swift, generics

Say I have a protocol:

```
protocol VehicleModel {...}
```

It is implemented by a number of different structs. (e.g. CarModel, TruckModel, etc.)
I have a generic method to get the vehicle's 'model identifier'.

```
func modelIdentifierForVehicle<V: VehicleModel>(vehicleType: V.Type) -> String {
  return "\(vehicleType)"
}
```

If I call modelIdentifierForVehicle(CarModel.self) this returns "Car" just fine. But if I have a polymorphic collections of VehicleModel's and I try to call modelIdentifierForVehicle(model.dynamicType) on each of them, Xcode says "Cannot invoke 'modelIdentifierForVehicle' with argument list of type (VehicleModel.Type)" Why is this? And how can I work around it?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code inside of `VehicleModel` and  `modelIdentifierForVehicle`?

Comment: @ABakerSmith Sure I updated the post. Basically it makes a unique key for the vehicle type because types themselves are not Hashable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only converting `vehicleType` to a `String` in `modelIdentifierForVehicle`, I would argue why you need to use constrain `V` to `VehicleModel`, or even use generics at all:

```
func typeIdentifier(t: Any.Type) -> String {
    return "\(t)"
}  

let vehicles: [VehicleModel.Type] = [CarModel.self, TruckModel.self]
typeIdentifier(vehicles[0]) // CarModel
```

---

If there's a reason you need use a `VehicleModel`, assuming `VehicleModel` doesn't use `Self` or associated type requirements, you could do:

```
func modelIdentifierForVehicle(vehicleType: VehicleModel.Type) -> String {
    return "\(vehicleType)"
}
```

---

If you're using Swift 2, you could instead use a protocol extension:

```
extension VehicleModel {
    static var modelIdentifier: String {
        return "\(self.dynamicType)"
    }
}

// The array from earlier.
vehicles[1].modelIdentifier // TruckModel.Type
```